# No guarda datos en base de datos C#

Tags: c#

tengo este codigo, pero no me inserta los datos en la base de datos, pero no me marca ningun error.

```
          foreach (DataRow r in datasetexcelcont.Tables[0].Rows) {
            DataRow dr = cobranzaDataSet3.Cartera.NewRow();
            dr[0] = r[0];
            dr[1] = r[1];
            dr[2] = r[2];
            dr[3] = r[3];
            dr[4] = r[4];
            dr[5] = r[5];
            dr[6] = r[6];
            dr[7] = r[7];
            dr[8] = r[8];
            dr[9] = r[9];
            dr[10] = r[10];
            dr[11] = r[11];
            dr[12] = r[12];
            dr[13] = r[13];
            dr[14] = r[14];
            dr[15] = r[15];
            dr[16] = r[16];
            dr[17] = r[17];

            cobranzaDataSet3.Cartera.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        this.carteraTableAdapter.Update(this.cobranzaDataSet3.Cartera);
```

si necesitan mas codigo para entender me dicen y coloco todo.
Gracias por ayudar, no encuentro nada.
por cierto estoy usando base de datos access.

Comment: Al invocar al método `Update` puedo suponer que estás realizando una actualizando de registro, has intentado con un método de insercción `Insert` (Algo así).

Comment: lo intenté con insert, pero no se cual es el valor que se debe de tomar, ya que tome los valores de dr y r, pero me marcaba error

Comment: El código que muestras aparentemente no tiene error. Pero intenta hacerlo de otra forma: en vez de declarar ´DataRow dr = cobranzaDataSet3.Cartera.NewRow()
´, utiliza algo como ´cobranzaDataSet3.CarteraRow dr = cobranzaDataSet3.Cartera.NewRow()
´ y en vez hacer la asignación ´dr[0] = r[0]´ utiliza ´dr.NombreDeColumna = r[0]´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es probable que necesites un **SqlCommandBuilder**

Primero creas el command builder:

```
 SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder;
 commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(this.carteraTableAdapter);
```

después utilizas el objeto **commandBuilder** para generar los queries que vas a necesitar para tus operaciones:

```
this.carteraTableAdapter.DeleteCommand = commandBuilder.GetDeleteCommand(true);
this.carteraTableAdapter.UpdateCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand(true);
this.carteraTableAdapter.InsertCommand = commandBuilder.GetInsertCommand(true);
```

y al final estaras listo para realizar las operaciones de tu código

```
foreach (DataRow r in datasetexcelcont.Tables[0].Rows) {
    DataRow dr = cobranzaDataSet3.Cartera.NewRow();
    dr[0] = r[0];
    dr[1] = r[1];
    dr[2] = r[2];
    dr[3] = r[3];
    dr[4] = r[4];
    dr[5] = r[5];
    dr[6] = r[6];
    dr[7] = r[7];
    dr[8] = r[8];
    dr[9] = r[9];
    dr[10] = r[10];
    dr[11] = r[11];
    dr[12] = r[12];
    dr[13] = r[13];
    dr[14] = r[14];
    dr[15] = r[15];
    dr[16] = r[16];
    dr[17] = r[17];

    cobranzaDataSet3.Cartera.Rows.Add(dr);
}
this.carteraTableAdapter.Update(this.cobranzaDataSet3.Cartera);
```

Comment: Gracias, si me funcionó

Answer (score 0):

this.carteraTableAdapter.Update(this.cobranzaDataSet3.Cartera);
//
te falta agregar un comando 
ejemplo

adapter.Update (table.Select ( nulo , nulo , DataViewRowState.Added));